# RSpec/Capybara does not commit to DB within test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm quite desperate since moving our test suite from Minitest to RSpec. All the controller and model tests run fine so far, but since trying to port (formerly passing/working) feature tests like the following I ran into trouble...

```
feature 'Create place' do
  scenario 'create valid place as user' do
    login_as_user
    visit '/places/new'
    fill_in_valid_place_information
    click_button('Create Place')
    visit '/places'
    expect(page).to have_content('Any place', count: 1)
  end

  ...

  def fill_in_valid_place_information
      fill_in('place_name', with: 'Any place')
      fill_in('place_street', with: 'Magdalenenstr.')
      fill_in('place_house_number', with: '19')
      fill_in('place_postal_code', with: '10963')
      fill_in('place_city', with: 'Berlin')
      fill_in('place_email', with: 'schnipp@schnapp.com')
      fill_in('place_homepage', with: 'http://schnapp.com')
      fill_in('place_phone', with: '03081763253')
  end
end
```

Unfortunately this does not lead to a DB commit which makes the test fail. It does not fail if i `pry` into the test and manually create the requested place. I tried different methods in order to trigger the button but nothing worked so far.

This is how my `rails_helper.rb` looks like:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
require 'pry'

def validate_captcha
  fill_in 'captcha', with: SimpleCaptcha::SimpleCaptchaData.first.value
end

def login_as_user
  user = create :user, email: 'user@example.com'
  visit 'login/'
  fill_in 'sessions_email', with: 'user@example.com'
  fill_in 'sessions_password', with: 'secret'
  click_on 'Login'
end

Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, phantomjs_options: ['--ignore-ssl-errors=true'])
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, no_transaction: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each, js: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.include Capybara::DSL
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
end
```

Does anyone have a clue about a possible cause? Gem versions:

- capybara 2.12.0
- rspec 3.5.0
- rails 4.2.7.1

best and thanks,
Andi

--- **Update**

I added `fill_in_valid_place_information` method

This is how the test fails with or without a Capybara JS driver enabled (shouldn't matter in case of this test as the feature does not use any JS). Unfortunately it doesn't give any real hints to work with...

```
1) Create place create valid place as user
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content('Any place', count: 1)

       expected to find text "Any place" 1 time but found 0 times in "KIEZ KARTE Find places Here comes a list of all POIs currently available in our database. If you are looking for a specific location please enter parts of its descriptive features into the 'Search' field. Search: Name Postal code Categories No data available in table"

       Timeout reached while running a *waiting* Capybara finder...perhaps you wanted to return immediately? Use a non-waiting Capybara finder. More info: http://blog.codeship.com/faster-rails-tests?utm_source=gem_exception
```

--- **Update 2**

I found the issue which is not capyara-related. Actually I forgot to transfer a stub response for an API we're calling. Thanks everybody for participating in my struggle!

Comment: Can you post fill_in_valid_place_information method?

Comment: Hey, thanks. I updated the answer to include the method and the failure message (which is not of much help)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of potential issues in your test that could be causing what you are seeing, it would be easier to narrow down in the future if you included the actual error message(s) your test produces.

1. Your scenarion/feature isn't tagged with :js metadata to activate using the Capybara driver.  It's possible you've specified `Capybara.default_driver` somewhere, but if so then your DatabaseCleaner config is wrong
2. Use the recommended DatabaseCleaner configuration from  https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example .  The driver name detection will work if you have specified `Capybara.default_driver` as mentioned in #1 and also with the :js/:driver metadata usage pattern.  Additionally, the append_after/after difference is important to reduce test flakiness
3. Your `login_as_user` method needs to verify the login has completed before returning.  This is because `click_on 'Login'` can trigger asynchronously and return before the login actually occurs.  This leads to the `visit` you call immediately following aborting the login, preventing the session cookie from being sent, and ending up with a non logged in user when you expected the user to be logged in.  To fix this you need something like

   ```
   def login_as_user
     ...
     click_on 'Login'
     expect(page).to have_text('You are now logged in!') #whatever message is shown on successful login, or use have_css with some element on the page that only exists when a user is logged in (user menu, etc)
   end
   ```

   The same issue exists between `click_button('Create Place')` and `visit '/places'` where the visit can effectively cancel the effects of the button click

Comment: Hey Thomas, thanks for your comprehensive answer. 1. The feature tested does not comprise any JS. Anyhow, it fails even with :js tag. 2. I did, changes nothing. 3. The login has completed, I verfyied that. Even without login the logic of the software allows submitting so this cannot be an issue. Additionally: The test as it is works - "conceptually" - under Minitest -.-

Comment: @A.Neumann Does your code depend on an `after_commit` callback?

Comment: It does, I have two `after_create` callbacks

Comment: @A.Neumann Also, can you show your create action, and relevant output in your test log.  Note - if using a JS driver you have the same issue between `click_button('Create Place')` and `visit '/places'` as with the login -- the visit can effectively cancel the create.  If you output page.html after the click_button('Create Place') does it show any errors?

Comment: @A.Neumann  `after_create` is different than `after_commit` - after_create should be fine but `after_commit` isn't called when in transaction mode.

Comment: Allright, I've got it, it's a little emberassing. I forgot to stub the response of a geocoding API so the respective callback could not assign lat/lon values. `tail -f log/test.log` revealed it, thanks a thousand for this tip!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135308/discussion-between-a-neumann-and-thomas-walpole).